# Prestashop - Need to add extra variables in the payment.html file

Tags: php, prestashop

I am trying to add variables in the `payment.html` file but can't figure out which files the variables are passed from.

Current there are variables that are passing: `total_paid` and I can't seem to figure out what file this variable is getting passed from.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure this out.

It is in the orderHistory file class/order/orderHistory.php

Check function addWithemail and add new fields to the $data array:
Example:

```
        $data = array(
            '{lastname}' => $result['lastname'],
            '{firstname}' => $result['firstname'],
            '{id_order}' => (int)$this->id_order,
            '{order_name}' => $order->getUniqReference(),
            '{order_receipt}' => 'R'.sprintf('%06d', $order->id),
            '{order_invoice}' => 'W'.sprintf('%06d', $order->id),
            '{order_date}' => date('d/m/Y')
        );
```